# disable links when user did not log in with an account

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, wampserver

Good day!
I'm just wondering if it is possible to disable links if the user didn't log-in in my website. Just like other websites, I allowed the visitors to enter the website without logging in but I want to prohibit them from using some features of the website which are intended only for those who have accounts. I'm not really good at this. I was thinking also to disable some links also according to user ID. I mean, there are some features who are just intended for the administrator. If the user who logged in is not the administrator he can't also use the administrator's page link.

Comment: create users then assign roles to them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it with PHP. make a script that check if the user is logged, then submit the links to the HTML page, else, don't submit.

Comment: can you help me with the coding? Please?

Comment: add a colum to you `"users" table` named `user_level`, then make something like this in your pages:

`<?php if ( $user_level >= 1 ) : ?>
 //html content to be showed
<?php endif // $user_level >= 1 ?>`

Comment: Note that the html content should be anything. You can, for example, write CSS code to hide all the links with the class you want. for example:
`<style>.adminLink {
display:none;
}</style>`
This will hide all the links with `class="adminLink"`